# _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making an application that involves tkinter, and will eventually involve sockets. My code currently consists of this:

```
import tkinter as tk # imports tkinter module
from tkinter import * # imports tkinter module

a=tk.Tk()
a.title('Custodian Alert Tool')
List=['','','']
List.clear()

def Clear():
            for widget in a.winfo_children(): # clears the window for the next Page
                        widget.destroy()

def Home():
            Clear()
            Label(a,text='Welcome to the Custodian Alert Tool.').pack()
            Label(a,text='').pack()
            SubmitButton=tk.Button(a,text='Submit A Ticket',command=Submit)
            SubmitButton.pack()
            ExitButton=tk.Button(a,text='Exit',command=Exit)
            ExitButton.pack()
            a.mainloop()

def Submit():
            Clear()
            def Append1(): # the button calls this function when pressed
                        List.append(x.get())
                        Gender()
            Label(a,text='Which bathroom are you reporting for?').pack()
            f=tk.Frame(a)
            f.pack()
            x=tk.StringVar()
            E=tk.Entry(f,textvariable=x)
            E.grid(row=1,column=1)
            b1=tk.Button(f,text='Submit',command=Append1) # the error occurs after I click this button
            b1.grid(row=1,column=2)

def Gender():
            Clear()
            def Append2(y):
                        List.append(y)
                        Issue()
            Label(a,text='Boys or Girls?').pack()
            f=tk.Frame(a)
            f.pack()
            b1=tk.Button(f,text='Boys',command=Append2('Boys'))
            b1.grid(row=1,column=1)
            b2=tk.Button(f,text='Girls',command=Append2('Girls'))
            b2.grid(row=1,column=2)
def Issue():
            Clear()


def Exit():
            a.destroy()

Home()
```

When I click the b1 button under the Submit function, however, I get this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/skor8427/Desktop/AlertClient.py", line 27, in Append1
    Gender()
  File "/Users/skor8427/Desktop/AlertClient.py", line 45, in Gender
    b1=tk.Button(f,text='Boys',command=Append2('Boys'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2209, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2139, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".4610182280"
```

This is the biggest error I have ever gotten and I have no clue where to begin. Anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do this:

```
b1=tk.Button(f,text='Boys',command=Append2('Boys'))
```

It behaves exactly the same as this:

```
result = Append2('Boys'))
b1=tk.Button(f,text='Boys',command=result)
```

When `Append2` is called, it calls `Issue` which calls `Clear` which destroys all of the children in `a`. `f` is in `a` so `f` gets destroyed. That means that you're trying to create `b1` as a child of a widget that has been destroyed. And *that* is why you get the error "bad window path name" -- that cryptic string is the name of the widget that has been destroyed.

You need to modify the construction of `b1` to be something like this:

```
b1 = Button(f, text='Boys', command=lambda: Append2('Boys'))`
```

That will defer the calling of `Append2` until the button is clicked.